# Unable to do git pull due to permission denied could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm the owner of the remote repo. I can do `git push` easily. However, when I tried to do `git pull` to align my local with the remote repo, I got this error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I spent hours to google for a solution but to no avail.

What is happening? I can understand if I can't do both `push` and `pull`. Could someone please help?

PS: when doing git `remote -v` I have the correct information

```
origin  git@github.com:<my github username>/<my github repo>.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<my github username>/<my github repo> (push)
```

Comment: what `git remote -v` outputs?

Comment: "Permission denied" means what it says. You have two different URLs you're using here. The push URL uses `https://`, i.e., a web server, where you'll need a user name and token. The pull URL uses `ssh://`, i.e., ssh authentication, where you'll need a public and private key-pair. You've clearly set up the web server authentication correctly, and the ssh key-pair authentication incorrectly. Fix the incorrect setup or use the web-server URL for fetch.